# Android client socket works on wifi but times out on 4G

Tags: java, android, sockets, 4g

I have an android app which works when I am connected to wifi, but not when I am connected through 4G.  To clarify, it works when I am connected to any wifi internet connection, not the network my server is on.  My manifest file contains:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

and the offending line is:

```
new Socket(InetAddress.getByName("mydomain.com"), XXXX);
```

which hangs and then gives me this error:

```
java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to mydomain.com/XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX (port XXXX): connect failed: ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)
```

which I printed to logcat.  I do not think it is a DNS problem because I successfully found the IP address with

```
System.out.println("Server IP:" + InetAddress.getByName("mydomain.com").toString());
```

I am running this on my Samsung S III phone.  Again, it works fine when I am connected to wifi or when I run it in an emulator, but the client Socket times out when my internet connection is 4G.  Any ideas why this would happen?

Comment: Can you reach the site from the device browser when on the mobile network?  Is the site indeed on the public Internet?  Perhaps your mobile and hosting ISP's are taking a business dispute out on their customers.  Or perhaps the mobile carrier finds your traffic or port choice suspicious.

Comment: Yes, I also host a website on the same server and can access it from the phone on 4G.

Comment: What port are you using?  What sort of traffic?  How long does it take to time out?  If you make your app do a pseudo-http request to your web service on port 80, does that work?  The idea is to try to narrow down what the differences are, *especially* to see if there's any hint the mobile ISP blocking specific characteristics of your traffic.

Comment: Good call, I was using port 4444.  If I make the socket connect to port 80, it connects.  I will try using another standard port which I am not using on my server, such as port 20.  Thanks!  On a side note, it seems pretty ridiculous to me that Verizon would block ports from the client side.